# collada 3D object mouse event

Tags: three.js, collada

Hello all,

I wnat to change color on 3D object(collada file) child when the mouse over.
I try to use **Raycaster** method, but it doesn't work.
like [this](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html) sample. 
but i want to change color or highlight a **model child** when the mouse over.

and this is my code.

```
                var oLoader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
                oLoader.load('model/sample.dae', function (collada) {

                    var object = collada.scene;
                    var skin = collada.skins[0]; 

                    object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
                    object.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
                    object.position.x = 0;
                    object.position.y = 0;
                    object.position.z = 0;
                    object.scale.set(0.025, 0.025, 0.025);
                    object.updateMatrix();
                    scene.add(object);
```

please tell me how to do.
Thanks very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coincidentally, i'm also working on a project requiring mouse events, and coded a small object to use.

```
var mouse = {
    getIntersects: function( camera, sceneChildren, event ){
        event = event || window.event;

        var mouseX = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        var mouseY = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouseX, mouseY, camera.near );
            vector.unproject( camera );

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( sceneChildren );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
            //console.log(intersects);
            return intersects;
        }
        return false;
    },

    Position3D: function(sceneChildren){
        var intersects = mouse.getIntersects( sceneChildren );
        return intersects[0].point
    }
}
```

i dont know if you want to use this object on its own, or use it as a reference to code something yourself, but here's how you use it:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var intersectObj = mouse.getIntersects( camera, scene.children, event)[0];
    if(window.console){ 
        console.log(intersectObj);
    }
    else{
        alert(intersectObj);
    }
});
```

now that you have the clicked object all sorted out, you can get started on the functions. The simplest way is to just add them to the mesh. so:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.click = function(){
        alert('object was clicked');
    }
```